# Biblatex: How do I suppress a comma after the title?

Tags: biblatex

I'm relatively new to Latex, and very new to Biblatex. I need to replicate an MHRA reference style. I've almost got it, except for a comma, after the title, which I need suppressed. How would I achieve this?[image: Unwanted Comma]

Here's my Biblatex code:

```
    \usepackage[backend=biber,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex}
    \renewbibmacro{in:}{}
    \setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}
    \addbibresource{references.bib}
    \renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
    \DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}

    \printbibheading
    \printbibliography[type=book,heading=subbibliography,title={Book Sources}]
```

Here is a link for it:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gjoSVxXXhkgLqGFHpaNCAbqpa9YpPRq5?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to your preamble does the job:

```
\usepackage{xpatch} 

\xpatchbibdriver{book}{%
\printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock}{%
 \printfield{note}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock}
{}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that doesn't seem to do anything when I add it to the preamble :(

Comment: And with `\AtBeginBibliography{...}`? If it doesn't work, please post a small compilable example.

Comment: I've edited the link to a compilable example in the main question. The \AtBeginBibliography{...}, didn't work as well.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood the problem. I've posted a solution with `xpatch`.